# Цикл произвольной глубины массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. Каждый объект имеет координаты. Уровни вложенности различные, как и количество пар координат. Проблема в том, что для создания слоев они подходят, а для перехода по ссылке эти координаты нужно реверсировать(reverse(), например). Как задать цикл таким образом, чтобы он прошел по всем парам координат и поменял их местами?

```
var ao=[
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "properties": 
        {
            "NAME": "Центральный", 
            "ABBREV": "ЦАО"
        }, 
        "geometry": 
        { 
            "type": "Polygon", 
            "coordinates": 
            [ 
                [ 
                    [ 37.51393, 55.75842 ],
                    [ 37.51567, 55.75909 ] 
                ], 
                [ 37.51927, 55.76047 ], 
                [ 37.51993, 55.76072 ], 
                [ ... ] 
            ... 
            ]] 
        }
    }, и т.д.
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дак вы разбейте задачу на шаги. Во-первых вам надо рекурсивно обойти массив. Во вторых вам нужен признак конца рекурсии, в котором надо определить, что массив имеет два элемента, и это числа (достаточно первый проверить).

```js
var data =  [ 
                [ 
                    [ 1, 2 ],
                    [ 3, 4 ] 
                ], 
                [ 5, 6 ], 
                [ 7, 8 ],             
            ];
            
            

function mapper(v){
    if(v.length == 2 && typeof v[0] == 'number'){
        return [v[1], v[0]];
    } 
    return v.map(mapper);
}      
   
var result = data.map(mapper);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (в функцию передавать объект coordinates):

```
 function reverse(array) {
                    var lat, lng;
                    array.forEach(function (item, index) {
                        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
                            reverse(item)
                        } else {
                            index === 0 && (lat = item);
                            index === 1 && (lng = item);
                        }
                    });
                    if (lat && lng) {
                        array[0] = lng;
                        array[1] = lat;
                    }
                }
```